# NEXUS 7 "It seems that you device does not support camera"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

I am doing an application based in OpenCV, but this week I change my developer's device, I change my "BQ Edison" for a "Nexus 7".
Now, when I run my app, appear a message "It seems that you device does not support camera( or  it is locked). Application will be closed"
Why?

Ps: My Nexus 7 has got Android 4.2.2

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Nexus 7 does not have a back camera while BQ Edition does.
If you did not change your code you are still trying to get the back camera that is why you get an error.

[This post](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android2.3.0#Use_native_camera_in_your_cmake_project) from the OpenCV FAQ might help.

Here is a code snippet in case the link dies :

```
cv::VideoCapture capture(CV_CAP_ANDROID + 0); // "+ 0" for the back camera
cv::VideoCapture capture(CV_CAP_ANDROID + 1); // "+ 1" for the front camera for Android 2.3.3 or newer
```

Could you show some of your code to help identify the most appropriate syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue on my Nexus 7 2013. Using ADB I found that (under the 4.3 version of the OS) the camera enumeration functions were reporting camera resolution values that were causing the camera init to fail.  I updated to the 4.4 OS and the problem went away.  YMMV.